# Selenium Java: I want to access first div element inside a div class

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Selenium Java: I want to access first div element inside a div class

```
public int checkLinks()
    {

int x = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='recommendation-header-social-container']/div")).size();
        List<WebElement> y = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='recommendation-header-social-container']/div"));
        int i=0;
        for(WebElement element:y)
        {       
        String btn=element.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='recommendation-header-social-container']")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
            System.out.println("Length of first element: "+btn.length());

        }
            return x;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Xpath:

```
String btn=element.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='recommendation-header-social-container'])[1]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Or use css selector

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.recommendation-header-social-container > div:nth-child(1)"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use index of elements, ie. if you want to find out **first div** then just use **div[1]** at the end of xpath locator or if you want to get **second div** then **div[2]** and so on, like this:

*WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("abc[1]"));*

So, this will be answer for your question as per the give code:

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='recommendation-header-social-container']/div[1]"));

Comment: Tried this solution but getting the same output which we get without div

Comment: Sorry, i think i did Typo while writing the code, try "div[1]" instead of "div[0]" at the end. (i have also corrected it in my answer).
If it does not work then can you tell me what is the value of x as per your above given code?

Comment: Even if i give div[1], it gives "NoSuchEelementException" error.

Comment: ohk, its hard to tell the exact answer without looking at html of that page, may be you check if this locator is not present inside the 'IFRAME' tag. 
Else you can add full html of that page here so that we can debug this issue.