# Find new elements in selenium testing

Tags: java, selenium, testing, testng

Héy guys , first time here and wanted to ask about one question , i made a selenium test case where :
sign in outlook -> send a message -> go to "sent messages" -> delete the message

problem here is every new message has a new element (id or xpath or class..) so i always have to change it in my code , my question is do you guys know any way to do it (test case) without constently changing the element in my java code ?
Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48591753/selenium-java-i-want-to-access-first-div-element-inside-a-div-class) can help.

Comment: share the html or url in question?

Comment: Also: Do you have to send a message through outlook? Or can you use SMTP protocol rather than the web itsself?

Comment: Should be easy enough to find a message by unique subject line as xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Does the test have to target a **specific message** that was sent?

If its really just "go and delete a sent message" why not just simplify the case and delete the first or last sent message from the list?

Comment: Imagin i sent a message "Test" to a myself , and i want to delete it with selenium , in my "message sent" box it ll be the first one , how can i delete it ?

Answer (score 0):

There should be element which contains all massages. if you get xpath of that element then u can find childe elements.
you can read more here -https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/complete-guide-for-using-xpath-in-selenium-with-examples/

Comment: It's not about finding a child elements but , lets say the first element in "sent messages" wich i want to delete , but every message has its own element that changes so if i run my test case , and want to run it another time i have to modify xpath or id elements , so want something more "dynamic"